# Present View Controller without being on a View Controller - Swift / Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm creating an app that implements a **Facebook** and a **Twitter** service. In my view I have a button that toggles sharing on **Facebook/Twitter** or not. If **Facebook/Twitter** aren't connected, then the button will show "connect to".

When I click the button, a method in my controller (not my viewcontroller) will try to toggle the value because this controller tracks the state of my app. When I'm not connected to a social network my controller will notice and will call the correct service. This service will start a webview to provide the user credentials.

**And now my question:**

When I'm in my service and I need to provide credentials via a webview. When I want to show this webview I need to pass a `View Controller` that will handle the presenting. How do I provide a viewcontroller here?

Approaches I found:

- Call the appdelegate singleton and get the current presenting
  viewcontroller (I find this dirty but correct me if I'm wrong).
- Since I'm injecting my service into my controller in
  appdelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I could inject the UIWindow
  of the appdelegate and ask for the current presenting viewcontroller
  (Is almost the same as the first approach)
- Create a protocol implemented by a viewcontroller. The service has a property that is equal to that protocol and in my app delegate inject the
  viewcontroller into the service.
- Have a property in your controller
  that will be the presentingviewcontroller and let your controller
  implement the approach #3 protocol. When a function of that protocol
  is fired, the controller will handle it and use the
  presentingviewcontroller property for the webview. I only need to
  inject a viewcontroller into my controller in the appdelegate.
- Don't implement anything view related in that service.

My current implementation is approach #3.

If some things are not clear, please let me know.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tell me name and type of all the classes you used in your query?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by types/classes in your query. Could you please give some more information?

Answer (score 2):

I was hoping this question would of got more attention, I was interested to know how other people would handle this situation.

As you have already stated, there are a few ways to achieve what you need, but the answer depends on having knowledge of the application.

I would definitely try to keep business logic and UI as separate as possible, there are two methods that I can think of to do this, but they are pretty much the same thing.

1. Make the (non UI) controller responsible for the login check with a callback function, you can then leave the controller responsible for business logic and the calling ViewController responsible for rendering any UI as a result of that check.
2. As you suggested, using protocols, your controller could have a delegate that will be a ViewController that conforms to your protocol. Then usage would just be getting your shared instance, setting the delegate and calling the required fuctionality.

I would likely favor option 2 to be more Swift-like as it is a protocol orientated language.

If the controller is acting globally and accessed from anywhere within the application you could potentially end up duplicating a lot of code to make these checks, you could get around this by creating an extension of UIViewController which provides the functionality to interact with the controller.

I hope this helps, Would definitely be interesting to see the way other people would approach this.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! 
I think option 2 is really good but than your controller is dependent on your facebook service/sdk (not sure if that is a bad thing tho since your controller handles all the business logic). The reason I went for my approach was that I wanted my facebook service to handle all the logic because if I ever want to use a different facebooksdk (probably never going to happen) I only had to change my service class. That is the reason I have a protocol with a viewcontroller in my service.

Comment: Yeah I agree, The only thing is it does have UI to it, but your Social Service could just use the app delegate to get the currently presented VC and use that, if you wanted it decoupled completely, but like you say. your not really likely to replace Facebook as a social platform are you. It does make sense to keep it self contained though in this case. I'll keep an eye on this question and see if we get any more answers, someone may come along with a much better solution entirely